# Converting a python server request into unity

Tags: c#, python, web, unity-game-engine

I was hitting my head around getting a web authentication request made in python to unity, can any one help me with this.

here what the 'auth' keyword means, and how do i form the same form unity C#.
i am new to unity networking concepts, please help me in this.

```
This is my python code:

r = requests.post("my url",
auth = (client_id,client_secret),
data = { 'grant_type' : 'password',
'username' : username, 
'password' : password })

if r. status_code == 200: { my code ...}

In unity i dont know how to write this, i read through WWW,WWWForm classes and used headers also like shown below but always getting 404 error. page not displayed.

This is my unity code :

publicvoidRequestUserLogin(stringpUsername, stringpPassword)
{

Dictionary<string,string> authHeader = newDictionary<string,string> ();
authHeader.Add (mS_Client_Id, mS_Client_Secret);

WWWForm form = newWWWForm();
WWW WWWLogin;

form.AddField ("grant_type", "password");
form.AddField ("username", "dumandu1");
form.AddField ("password", "pwd");
Hashtableheaders = form.headers;
headers ["auth"] = System.Convert.ToBase64String
(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mS_Client_Id+":"+mS_Client_Secret));

stringurl = "my url";

WWWLogin = newWWW(url,form);
StartCoroutine(Example(WWWLogin));

}

IEnumeratorExample(WWWWWWLogin) 
{

yield return WWWLogin;

if (WWWLogin.error == null)
{
  Debug.Log("WWW Login Success: "+ WWWLogin.error);
  if (WWWLogin.text != null) 
  {
    Debug.Log("WWW Login Text: "+ WWWLogin.text);
  }
} 
else
{
  Debug.Log("WWW Login Error: "+ WWWLogin.error);
} 

}
```

for this i am always getting the 404 page not displayed error. code is working fine in python and getting proper response from server.

am i doing anything wrong here.

```
any help would be great .
thank you.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified Post (Answer) :

public void RequestUserLogin(string pUsername, string pPassword)
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

```
    form.AddField ("username", pUsername);
    form.AddField ("password", pPassword);
    form.AddField ("grant_type", "password");

    Hashtable headers = form.headers;
    byte[] rawData = form.data;

    headers ["Authorization"] = "Basic "+ System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mS_Client_Id+":"+mS_Client_Secret));
    string url = "My URL";

    WWW WWWLogin = new WWW(url,rawData,headers);
    StartCoroutine(Example(WWWLogin));
}

IEnumerator Example(WWW WWWLogin) 
{
    yield return WWWLogin;

    if (WWWLogin.error == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("WWW Login Success: "+WWWLogin.text);
    }  
    else 
    {
        Debug.Log("WWW Login Error: "+ WWWLogin.error);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure that you're using all the necessary data when calling any function.

In this case, you're leaving the headers out. `new WWW(url, form)` will create a request with no headers. What you want is:

`WWWLogin = new WWW(url, form, headers);`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah i found this , forgot to post it here. Thank you for the Answer.